# Why my first tab is not displayed?

Tags: android, tabs

I have created a Tab Activity showing a number of tabs defined in an xml string array. Each tab has the same listview as content which I update with different data.
I can see my tabs and the content updated each time I click on a tab, but the first tab (when activity is created) is never displayed.

I can see in my logs that onTabChanged is called when onCreate is executing, but the result is not displayed. If I change selected tab and go back to the first, I can see it.

This is my code :

```
public class MyActivity extends TabActivity {
    protected final void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LOGGER.debug("onCreate.start");

        setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        adapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), new ArrayList<Station>());
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        final Resources res = getResources();
        final TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener(
            (MyApplication) getApplicationContext()));

        TabHost.TabSpec spec;

        final String[] tabsString = res.getStringArray(R.array.tabs);
        for (int i = 0; i < tabsString.length; i++) {
            final String[] tab = tabsString[i].split("\\|");
            spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(tab[0]).setIndicator(tab[1]);
            spec.setContent(R.id.tabcontent);

            tabHost.addTab(spec);

            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().width = TAB_WIDTH;
        }

        LOGGER.debug("onCreate.end");
    }


    public void onTabChanged(final String tabId) {

        LOGGER.debug("onTabChanged.start");

        refreshTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Station>>() {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {

                /* Show progress bar and hide list view. */
                findViewById(R.id.loading).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                findViewById(R.id.listview).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            };

            @Override
            protected List<Station> doInBackground(final Void... params) {

                return getStations(0, 0, tabId);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(final List<Station> result) {

                if (result != null) {
                    adapter.setStations(result);
                } else {
                    adapter.clear();
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                /* Hide progress bar and show list view. */
                findViewById(R.id.loading).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                findViewById(R.id.listview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        };

        refreshTask.execute();

        LOGGER.debug("onTabChanged.end");
    }
}
```

And this is the log I can see in LogCat console :

```
MyActivity        onCreate.start
MyActivity        onTabChanged.start
MyActivity        onTabChanged.end
MyActivity        onCreate.end
```

Do you have an idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Following Line of code is causing problem
adapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), new ArrayList());
you are passing arralist with size 0 hence no data displayed.
But when tab changes at then  in your listener you passing arralist which contains some data and hence you are able to see data when you come back.
Enjoy..

Comment: Good catch.  Also, you shouldn't be using the application context right there.   Use the activity context by assigning 'this'.

Comment: Yes, I initialize my adapter with no data. When onTabChanged is called by onCreate() (because first tab is displayed by default), I update this adapter with data, but this is not enough and my tab content is always empty.
I have to select the second tab and come back to the first to see something in the first.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the first tab as active at the end of your onCreate after you create all the tabs:

```
tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

Comment: I have already try that and it does not change. Indeed, the first tab is already selected by default.